# upgrading to 14.04 problem

Tags: resolution, screen

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 but now my screen size has shrunk, it seems like the desktop size is the same, but I now have a large border and small viewing screen. I have tried to re-size my laptop but can't get anywhere. Why am I having this problem and how do I get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Once you are booted up to the blank desktop... press CTRL + ALT + F1.

```
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get install unity
apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee*
apt-get install nvidia-prime
shutdown -r now
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, i will try this , then let you know if it worked or not.

Comment: i have tried this, but the laptop requires a password after i have pressed CTRL+ALT+F1, unfortunately i do not know the password to continue any further, is there any way round this or another solution to my problem

Comment: Then probably you should go for resetting the password. Once it is done you can perform the above steps to get rid of your issue. Please refer the following links for resetting the passwords....(https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword) and (http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)